# How to contain and compare string and array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, regex, spring, rest

I'm using array and for loop in condition if to compare 'searchedValue' and arrayParameter.

this is my code:

```
String[] arrayParameter = new String[] {
            "math",
            "physical",
            "literary"
};

boolean found = false;

String searchedValue = "math";
String searchedValue1 = "physical";
String searchedValue2 = "literary";

for(int i=0 ; i< arrayParameter.length; i++) {

    if(arrayParameter[i].equals(searchedValue)) {
        found = true;
        break;
    }
    else if(arrayParameter[i].equals(searchedValue1)) {

        found = true;
        break;
    }
    else if(arrayParameter[i].equals(searchedValue2)) {
        found = true;
        break;
    }
}

HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(arrayParameter[i],headers);
String result = restTemplate.postForObject(url, entity, String.class);

logger.debug(result);
```

When i run my code it cannot compare and return correct result.  How to compare/contains 'searchedValue' with 'arrayParameter[i]' and when string found program will stop and continue to outside of method ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You are using 'i' outside for loop, which is out of its scope.
- Your write too many if-else statements

```
boolean found = false;
String foundValue = null;

String searchedValue = "math";
String searchedValue1 = "physical";
String searchedValue2 = "literary";

for(int i=0 ; i< arrayParameter.length; i++) {

if(arrayParameter[i].contains(searchedValue) ||  arrayParameter[i].contains(searchedValue1) || arrayParameter[i].contains(searchedValue2)) {
    found = true;
    foundValue = arrayParameter[i];
    break;
}

}
HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(foundValue,headers);
String result = restTemplate.postForObject(url, entity, String.class);

logger.debug(result);
```

`Suggestion:`

You can use HashSet instead of String[] array. It will reduce your searching time.

O(1) search:

```
HashSet<String> setParameter = new HashSet<String>(); 

setParameter.add("math");
setParameter.add("physical");
setParameter.add("literary"); 

if(setParameter.contains(searchedValue) ||  setParameter.contains(searchedValue1) || setParameter.contains(searchedValue2)) {
    found = true;
    foundValue = arrayParameter[i];
    break;
}
```

Comment: Hi @Md. Kawser Habib:  first code seem it cannot get correct result, could you check it ?

Comment: result seem is random

Comment: @luongkhanh, please give me the expected input and output, it will be helpful.

Comment: Hi @Md. Kawser Habib: yes thank for your support

Comment: hi @Md. Kawser Habib: example: I input 'literary', and then it will contain and compare with array and return 'literary' (output)

Comment: Yes, literary will be the output then. Only one match(first match) will return in this case. Actually, you need only one searhValue, instead of multiple search values, otherwise, your output will be unpredictable in many cases or we should use different logic here.

Comment: yes so do we need to modify code for this case ?

Comment: Yeah, based on the situation we should/can modify code.

Comment: yes we should use different logic, let us modify, please support me for this case if you'are available

Answer (score 0):

I think you can easily use `Arrays.asList(arrayParameter).contains(searchedValue)` to create your intented approach. With this you can eliminate the loop.
Note that if you used exact below approach, your API won't called if there is no match.
But above you example API call goes even there is no matches, with `null` for foundValue.

```
if (Arrays.asList(arrayParameter).contains(searchedValue)){
    callApi(searchedValue)
}
if (Arrays.asList(arrayParameter).contains(searchedValue1)){
    callApi(searchedValue1)
}
if (Arrays.asList(arrayParameter).contains(searchedValue2)){
    callApi(searchedValue2)
}

private void callApi(String foundValue){
   
    HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(foundValue,headers);
    String result = restTemplate.postForObject(url, entity, String.class);
    logger.debug(result);
}
```